# PHP function containing a switch statement returns NULL, switch statement pasted directly works

Tags: php, mysql, switch-statement

PHP beginner here. I am working on a CRUD project to get a better understanding of MySQL and PHP.

I have come across an issue I need help with.

**DB structure:** I've got two tables in my database, 'lists' and 'categories'.
Inside a 'lists' table each list has a category assigned to it - 1, 2 or 3.
Inside a 'categories' table each category has an id - 1, 2 or 3 and name - X, Y and Z.

**What I want to do:** I want a user to see all lists and categories when they view page A. If they click a category X, they are taken to page B where only lists with category X are displayed.

**What I have so far:**

1. Inside my functions.php file I created this function:

```
function showListsByCat ($cat) {

            include 'includes/config.php';
        
                switch ($cat) {

                    case "X":
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM lists INNER JOIN categories ON lists.subject = categories.id WHERE categories.name = 'X';";
                        $results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                        break;
                      case "Y":
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM lists INNER JOIN categories ON lists.subject = categories.id WHERE categories.name = 'Y';";
                        $results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                        break;
                      case "Z":
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM lists INNER JOIN categories ON lists.subject = categories.id WHERE categories.name = 'Z';";
                        $results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                        break;
                      default:
                      header( "Location: index.php?error=noListsFound" );
                }
        }
```

1. Then, on page B I included functions.php and retrieve the query from the URL with $_GET. The URL looks something like this:
   http://localhost:8888/lists-category?cat=X
2. I save this in $query variable:  $query = $_GET['cat'] ? $_GET['cat'] : "";
3. Still inside page B file I paste the $query var to the showListsByCat function like this:

showListsByCat($query)

**Error:** This is returning NULL. However, if I paste the switch statement directly in the file, without it being inside a function, it works.

I hope this is clear and detailed enough - let me know if you have any ideas!

Comment: You do not return anything from your function

Comment: `this is returning null`...well your function doesn't contain a `return` statement, so that's kind of inevitable.

Comment: P.S. You really don't need a `switch` statement here...learn how to use prepared statements and parameters so you can directly pass the selected value into the WHERE clause of the query instead of hard-coding 3 copies of the query which only vary by one value. You can see some examples here: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli#prepared_select

Comment: Do I get it right that when there will be 100 categories, you will have write 100 blocks of code running SQL queries?

Comment: @ADyson ahh thank you so much, I was going to use one but was being overly cautious I suppose - this is my first PHP practice project and I tend to discard simple, imperfect solutions, go for the more advanced ones, then fail and procrastinate when trying to fix it. 
The link you posted was v helpful and I got it working, so I removed the switch statement :)

Comment: @krzyzws No worries, glad you made some progress. P.S. YourCommonSense is one of the most knowledgeable people in the php/mysql space on this site. In fact I think they wrote the site I linked you to above. But yeah occasionally a little mild sarcasm is employed in the comments, don't take it personally is my advice :-). I think the objective was to make you think there might be a better way, and to do some research (cos figuring it out yourself is the best way to learn sometimes). Whereas I saw you might be at a very early stage of your programming journey so I was a little more direct.